# Fraction class in Python returns invalid string

Tags: python

I am trying to use the Fraction class in python supplying a string as input and I can get it to work for some fractions, but it fails for others eg: 2.5/32 (ValueError).
I can't see anything in a quick glance at the documentation, that would explain this.
Any suggestions.

Comment: Do you mean `Fraction("2.5/32")`?

Comment: ...you really can't see why `2.5/32` might not be a valid fraction?

Comment: Don't glance at documentation; read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fractions.Fraction` only works with integers; `2.5` is not an integer. An equivalent fraction would be

```
f = fractions.Fraction(25, 320)
```

Comment: @DSM That does not work for me, at least not in Python 2.6. It "works" in 2.7, but seems to give a wrong answer of `Fraction(1,128)` (10x too small).

Comment: No, it works.  It doesn't work in Python 2.6 because that's too old, but it gives the right answer in 2.7 and beyond: `Fraction(Fraction(25, 10), 32) == 5/64`.  I used your 320 instead of the real 32, so it was off by a factor of 10.  Should've guessed it was me who screwed up, not Python. :^)